# Initialization texts appear in nano

Tags: server, init

When I am coding with nano on my ubuntu server, The initialization texts(The ones appear with [ok] before them) appear on the screen. I think I can explain it better with an image:

[image]

What can I do about it?

Comment: use `vi` ;-) just joking, interesting issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on a console or VTY?  Check your logging configuration.  You are seeing log output on the screen.  You can (try to) ignore it as it is only output, not input that nano/vi/vim/mcedit will see.

[ I'm adding this as an Answer as comments are prohibited if you don't have reputation >=50 ]